# How do I calculate the relative number of photons per wavelength emmited by the sun?

Tags: photons, thermal-radiation, sun, wavelength

Assume I generate $n$ photons emmited by the sun. They have wavelengths between 390 and 750 nanometers. How do I find out the number of photons that correspond to each wavelength:

How many of my $n$ photons should have a wavelength $\lambda$ with $\lambda \in [390, 750]$?

Comment: Are you familiar with a Planck spectrum?

Comment: @pela No, sadly I am not.

Comment: A [Planck spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) is the spectrum emitted by an object due to its temperature (as opposed to e.g. line emission), i.e. by a "blackbody". The answer to your question is the integral from 390 to 750 (expressed as number of photons rather than energy), divided by the total integral. I suggest you take a read at the linked article and come back if you have more questions :)

Comment: Thank you, I will do that.